# Submit slurm job script in sub-folders

Tags: bash, slurm

I have multi sub-folders (*say 1,2,3....*) inside a parent folder (*say A,B,C....*). Each script contains ".sh" file and associated loading files.

What would be the quick way to submit all the script files rather than moving across each sub-folder?

Comment: `sbatch` can't submit multiple scripts at the same time so you have no other choice than launching it for each script.

Comment: This is indeed very annoying. I ended up writing a [wrapper](https://gooseslurm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#module-GooseSLURM.cli.Gsub) because this problem occurs very frequently in my case

Answer (score 0):

If there are no similarities between these jobscripts then you might not have choice but to call sbatch multiple times as Fravadona says.

However, often if you find yourself in this situation it is probably the case that the jobscripts are similar and perform similar tasks, though with different working directories. In these cases you should use [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html):

> 1. It's less work for you (no need to generate and modify tons of different job-scripts that are almost identical).
> 2. The squeue command is more readable for everyone (the whole array is only 1 entry)
> 3. It's easier for support to help you.
> 4. The scheduler isn't overloaded. For safety, there is a max-size of the queue, so very large submissions *must* use arrays to avoid hitting this limit. It also affects the backfill algorithm when scheduling jobs.
> 5. Convenient to cancel every job in a given array if you discover some mistake.
> 6. Email notifications can be customised to be sent only when all jobs have finished.
> 7. It's vastly simpler to re-run an aborted simulation (for example when a `NODE_FAIL` occurs). E.g. if job 841342_**3** dies, then:
>
> ```bash
> sbatch --array=3 my_jobscript.sh
> ```

[source](https://www.c3se.chalmers.se/documentation/running_jobs/#running-job-arrays)

In your situation it could look something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH ...  # same flags as usual here

# Parse arguments
working_dirs=( "$@" )
working_dir=${working_dirs[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
# SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is the "index" for the job-array

# If working dir doesn't exist exit
if [[ "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID" >= "$#" ]]; then
    echo ERROR Array task ID $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID exceed the number of directories given > /dev/stderr
    exit 1 
elif [[ ! -d "$working_dir" ]]; then
    echo ERROR Working directory \"$working_dir\" does not exist for task $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi

# Change working directory
cd working_dir
echo Working diretory $(pwd) ($((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID + 1))/$#)

# Do the usual computations in this working directory
...
```

And then in your case you would call this function with (assuming 42 subdirectories)

```bash
sbatch --array=0-41 my_jobscript.sh [A-G]/[1-6]
```